# Сумма сумм в запросе

Tags: mysql

Есть такой запрос

```
    SELECT order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method,

    sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) paid,
    sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end) later,
  sum(case `order`.order_status when 'delivery-approved' then 1 else 0 end) deliveryapproved,
  sum(case `order`.order_status when 'problem' then 1 else 0 end) problem
FROM order_customFields 
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= '2016-12-01' AND
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date <= '2016-12-31' 
AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method is not null
GROUP BY    
   order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method
```

Который выводит данные в таком виде[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, возможно ли добавить условие, чтобы в этом же запросе выводилась новая строка, например "Европа", ячейки которой, были суммой данных 7 курьеров?

Comment: ROLLUP попробуйте. надо только придумать колонку, которая страну даст для последующей группировки и возможно подавить лишние итоги http://www.weblibrary.biz/mysql/funkcii/funkcii-group-by/modifikatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method,
      sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) paid,
      sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end) later,
      sum(case `order`.order_status when 'delivery-approved' then 1 else 0 end) deliveryapproved,
      sum(case `order`.order_status when 'problem' then 1 else 0 end) problem
FROM order_customFields 
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= '2016-12-01' AND
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date <= '2016-12-31' 
AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method is not null
GROUP BY    
   order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method

UNION 


SELECT 'EUROPE',
      sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) paid,
      sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end) later,
      sum(case `order`.order_status when 'delivery-approved' then 1 else 0 end) deliveryapproved,
      sum(case `order`.order_status when 'problem' then 1 else 0 end) problem
FROM order_customFields 
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= '2016-12-01' AND
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date <= '2016-12-31' 
AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method is not null
AND substr(order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method,1,3) ='eu_'
GROUP BY    
   substr(order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method,1,3)
```